# Why does memory NX need hardware support in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86

In Linux kernel, the page table entry (PTE) contains R/W bits but no eXecute bit because there is no NX bit in early x86 architecture.

I don't understand why X bit in PTE needs hardware support.

As I see, we can define a bit to struct PTE as X bit in kernel source code. Kernel will check this bit in PTE when accessing page table.

Any explanation will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because your scheme will break as soon as it runs on an architecture that [does not use that bit for NX](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121928/reserved-for-future-bits-in-microcontrollers).

Answer (score 0):

NX in software? Assuming the kernel can identify the cause of the trap being a memory load from the instruction queue instead of any arbitrary memory access, one would have to invalidate all pages* all the time to guarantee a trap from some arbitrary "jmp 0x1231231" instruction. That would be too costly for anything else, but an academic exercise.

(code pages could be whitelisted, but data pages couldn't)

Comment: After claiming "can't be done", the next question is: "how can it be done anyway?" Perhaps sections of instruction stream (loops?) can be analyzed to be safe and run without per-instruction protection.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware needs to distinguish between "reading data" and "reading code".  Before NX-bit support, if a page was readable at all, you could jump into it.

Aki's answer is the other side of the coin to what I said.  Doing NX without hardware support would require single-stepping every running process to check its jump / call instructions.  Either by parsing the instruction stream, or by invalidating all non-code pages before every instruction.  (And then marking them valid if it turns out the access was a load, not a jump.)